# My program prints random cards, but it will not recognize when there is a repeat card

Tags: c++

I am a beginner with C++ and have tried a few different things, but no matter what I try it doesn’t seem to recognize when a card has already been drawn...

I have tried to utilize to bool isDrawn, but after a few attempts of that with no success I am not 100% sure where to go from here

```
class Card {
  public:
    string suitName;
    int cardNumber;

    void printCard() {
      if (cardNumber == 1) {
        cout << "Ace";
      } else if (cardNumber == 11) {
        cout << "Jack";
      } else if (cardNumber == 12) {
        cout << "Queen";
      } else if (cardNumber == 13) {
        cout << "King";
      } else
        cout << cardNumber;
      cout << " of " << suitName << endl;
    }

    bool isDrawn = false;
};

class Deck {
  public:
    Card deck[52];

    void makeDeck(){
      int counter = 0;
      string suits[] = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds" };
      string face[] = { "Ace", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

      for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
          deck[counter].isDrawn = false;
          deck[counter].cardNumber = (j + 1);
          deck[counter].suitName = suits[i];
          counter++;
        }    
      }
    }

    Card drawCard() {
      int randcard;
      do {
        randcard = rand() % 52;
      } while (deck[randcard].isDrawn == true);
      return deck[randcard];
    }
};

class Player {
  public:
    vector<Card> hand;
    void setName(string s){
      name = s;
    }
    string printName(){
      return name;
    }
    void printHand() {
      for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++){
        hand.at(i).printCard();}
    }
  private:
    string name;
};

int main() {
  Deck my_deck;

  Player p1;
  p1.setName("HAL 9000");
  cout << p1.printName() << endl;
  my_deck.makeDeck();
  p1.hand.push_back(my_deck.drawCard());
  p1.hand.push_back(my_deck.drawCard());
  p1.hand.push_back(my_deck.drawCard());
  p1.printHand();
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You never set the isDrawn to true... Also a better way is to create the cards, shuffle them like in the real world and then just pick them one by one.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, you use `rand` but never call `srand`.

Comment: Please use [modern C++ random number facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is correct. Generate the pack ahead of time and just pop cards off it. Otherwise you are left with an algorithm that has an possibly unbounded run time, especially as the number of not yet drawn cards becomes smaller.